# Can I send support questions to Google via email?

Tags: google

I've got an issue with a Google app that is nonstandard, so I'd like to write a detailed explanation to the Google support team instead of using the standard forms. Which address do I have to send my request to? I did not find any support addresses even on the contact pages.

Comment: Have you tried posting on the [Help Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google does not accept general support queries via emails. They have three levels of support:

- help centers for individual products (mostly knowledge base style)
- help forums (mostly peer support, though occasionally a Google staffer will drop in)
- enterprise support (dedicated support staff, available to Apps Premier and Education customers only)